# Schengen visa refused to South African resident with refugee travel documents

Tags: schengen, portugal, schengen-visas, refugees

I was awarded a South African permanent resident certificate as a refugee under Section 27 of the Refugee Act. I am originally from the Congo.

I currently hold a South African green ID book and traveling documents (in lieu of a passport).

I have recently applied to France for a Schengen visa, but they've declined my application due to the travel documents. I would like to apply at the Portuguese consulate. Would it accept my documents? In the past, I have been able to travel to the US.

If everything else fails, I would like to apply for a Congolese national passport. However, I'm uncertain if I am allowed to do that, given the fact that I am a former refugee.

Comment: If you get a Congolese passport, you're saying that you're no longer a refugee and you may lose your South African refugee status.

Comment: When you indicate traveling documents, do you mean [this SA Convention 1951 Travel Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WkkA.jpg)?

Comment: Are you certain that your denial was "due to the travel documents"?  That would be highly unusual, since documents in lieu of a passport are indeed supposed to be accepted in lieu of a passport.  It's far more likely that there was some other aspect of your application that led to the refusal, in which case getting different documents is unlikely to help.  Applying at the Portuguese consulate is only going to work if you change your itinerary, since you must apply to the consulate that is indicated by the "main destination" rule.

Comment: Can you clarify the exact reason why France refused to issue you a visa?

Answer (score 1):

French consulate does not accept South African Refugee passport (1951), you were supposed to call them first that what I did and found out that they do not recognize it all.